# Seeking help to clear previous route on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, esp8266

I have a few forms where a button causes an action, e.g.

```
<form action="/W_OK" method ="get" autocomplete="off">
        <p><label id= wifi>%WIFISTATE%</label><p>
        <p><label><a href="wCrd.html">Wifi</a><label></p><br>
        <p><label id = ssid>%SSID%<label><p><br>
        <p><label id = ipaddr>%IPADDR%</label><p>
        <p><button type="submit" class="submitBtn">Accept</button></p>
</form>
```

When the submit button is pressed, the URL in the browser is 192.168.0.28\W_OK

And the route at /W_OK is processed like this:

```
server.on("/W_OK", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
      wifiMgr.useCredentials();
      request->send(LittleFS, FPSTR(string_indexHTML), String(),false, processor);
      });
```

The problem I have is that when the index HTML is loaded with the request->send, the URL is still 192.168.0.28\W_OK rather than just 192.168.0.28.

My question is what can I do to clear the extension? Why doesn't reloading the index page, clear the previous request? Is this a browser issue, an HTML issue, or something about how the request is handled?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you  are using to reload the page ?

Comment: can you redirect to `"/"` after request is served? or there must be no page reload?